# Using dplyr to summarize summed proportions by groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

I've been trying to summarize data by multiple groups, where the new column should be a summary of the proportion of one column to another, by these groups. Because these two columns never both contain a value, their proportions cannot be calculated per row.
Below is an example.

By, P_Common and Number7 groups, I'd like the total N_count/A_count

```
structure(list(P_Common = c("B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "E", 
"F", "G", "G", "B", "G", "E", "D", "F", "C"), Number_7 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
    N_count = c(0L, 4L, 22L, NA, 7L, 0L, 44L, 16L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), A_count = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0L, 4L, 7L, NA, 23L, 4L, 7L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))


P_Common    Number_7    N_count A_count
B           1           0       NA
B           1           4       NA
C           1           22      NA
C           1           NA      NA
D           2           7       NA
E           2           0       NA
E           2           44      NA
F           2           16      NA
B           1           NA      7
G           3           NA      NA
E           1           NA      23
D           2           NA      4
F           1           NA      7
C           1           NA      17
```

In this example there'd be quite some 0 / NA values but that's okay, they can stay in, but overall it would become like

```
P_Common    Number_7   Propo
B           1          0.571428571
C           1          1.294117647
D           2          1.75
... etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(P_Common, Number_7) %>% 
  summarise(Propo = sum(N_count, na.rm = T) / sum(A_count, na.rm = T))
```

```r
  P_Common Number_7   Propo
  <chr>       <int>   <dbl>
1 B               1   0.571
2 C               1   1.29 
3 D               2   1.75 
4 E               1   0    
5 E               2 Inf    
6 F               1   0    
7 F               2 Inf    
8 G               3   0
```

Comment: That's what I tried but when I implement this on my own dataset, Propo returns the same value for each combination of groups, regardless of whether I group by the first, second, or both columns.. Must be something else wrong.
EDIT: my mistake was using the dataset$ syntax before the column names within the dplyr argument

Comment: @Treebeard that seems like an issue of `plyr::summarise` vs dplyr::summarise, try `dplyr::summarise` as your summarise may have been masked